# Knockout add marker to Google map

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to add the marker in Google map.when clicking on an item from the list.
Right now its shows all the marker on load.
any idea, how to do show only that marker which place it clicked.

```
var data = [
    { tag: "places", name: 'Park Ave Penthouse', location: { lat: 40.7713024, lng: -73.9632393 } },
    { tag: "places", name: 'Chelsea Loft', location: { lat: 40.7444883, lng: -73.9949465 } },
    { tag: "places", name: 'Union Square Open Floor Plan', location: { lat: 40.7347062, lng: -73.9895759 } },
    { tag: "Hotel", name: 'East Village Hip Studio', location: { lat: 40.7281777, lng: -73.984377 } },
    { tag: "Hotel", name: 'TriBeCa Artsy Bachelor Pad', location: { lat: 40.7195264, lng: -74.0089934 } },
    { tag: "Hotel", name: 'Chinatown Homey Space', location: { lat: 40.7180628, lng: -73.9961237 } }
];

function point(tag, name,location) {
    var self = this;
    this.tag = ko.observable(tag);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.location = ko.observable(location);
}

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var googleMap = map;

    this.points = ko.observableArray('');
    this.selectedPoint = ko.observable('');

    this.setSelected = function (item) {
        self.selectedPoint(item);
    }

    this.justtags = ko.computed(function () {
        var tags = ko.utils.arrayMap(this.points(), function (item) {
            return item.tag();
        });
        return tags.sort();
    }, this);

    this.uniquetags = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(self.justtags()).sort();
    }, this);

    this.filteredNames = ko.computed(function () {
        var filter = self.selectedPoint()
        if (!filter) {
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.points(), function (item) {
                if (item.tag() === filter) {
                    return item
                };
            });
        }
    }, this);
}


var vm;
vm = new viewModel();

function initMap() {
    var map,i,position;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 40.7713024, lng: -73.9632393
        },
        zoom: 13
    });

    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        // console.log(data[i].location);
        position = data[i].location;

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map
        });

    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        vm.points.push(new point(item.tag, item.name, item.location));
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-inline" data-bind="foreach:uniquetags">
    <li data-bind="text:$data, click: $parent.setSelected"></li>
</ul>

<!--list of points-->
<ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach:filteredNames">
    <li data-bind="text:name"></li>
</ul>
<!--list of points end-->

<div id="map"></div>
```

any other suggestion?

Comment: I modified my answer from your original post.  is this what you are after?  https://jsfiddle.net/bdellinger/su14xuck/3/

Comment: @BryanDellinger, actually I am also adding the googlemap, when click on 'club' it give club list item and when click on any item, google marker show on google map. I find repo. http://museum.oxanaweb.com/
but my approch is different, when click on item from list, then pin will show. other wise it just the map

Answer (score 1):

ok, (I used the data from your original post) I think I'm close when you click one of the places it creates the markers (just couldn't figure out how to get rid of the old markers before making new ones) anyway run the snippet below.

```js
function loc(d) {
   var self = this;
   this.lat = ko.observable(d.lat);
   this.lng = ko.observable(d.lng);
 }

 function point(tag, name, location) {
   var self = this;
   this.tag = ko.observable(tag);
   this.name = ko.observable(name);
   this.location = new loc(location);
 }

 function viewModel() {
   var self = this;
   this.points = ko.observableArray('');
   this.selectedPoint = ko.observable('');

   this.setSelected = function(item) {
     self.selectedPoint(item);
     var locations = ko.toJS(self.filteredNames)
     $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: item.location,
         title: item.name
       });
       marker.setMap(map);
       map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
     });

   }

   this.justtags = ko.computed(function() {
     var tags = ko.utils.arrayMap(this.points(), function(item) {
       return item.tag();
     });
     return tags.sort();
   }, this);

   this.uniquetags = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
     return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(self.justtags()).sort();
   }, this);

   this.filteredNames = ko.computed(function() {
     var filter = self.selectedPoint()
     if (!filter) {} else {
       return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.points(), function(item) {
         if (item.tag() === filter) {
           return item
         };
       });
     }
   }, this);

 }



 var map;

 var data = [{
   tag: "places",
   name: "Dubai Marina",
   location: {
     lat: 24.4473236,
     lng: 54.3927349
   }
 }, {
   tag: "places",
   name: "Burj Khalifa",
   location: {
     lat: 24.4707202,
     lng: 54.3422700
   }
 }, {
   tag: "Coffee",
   name: "StarBucks",
   location: {
     lat: 24.4707202,
     lng: 54.3422700
   }
 }, {
   tag: "Coffee",
   name: "Costa",
   location: {
     lat: 24.4752239,
     lng: 54.3388363
   }
 }, {
   tag: "Club",
   name: "Beach Club",
   location: {
     lat: 24.4707202,
     lng: 54.3422700
   }
 }, {
   tag: "Club",
   name: "Cheers Club",
   location: {
     lat: 24.4707202,
     lng: 54.3422700
   }
 }];

 var vm = new viewModel();

 function initialize() {
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
   var myOptions = {
     zoom: 14,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.4481884, 54.3803007),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
   initialize();


   ko.applyBindings(vm);
   $.each(data, function(i, item) {
     vm.points.push(new point(item.tag, item.name, item.location))
   })
 });
```

```css
#map_canvas {
    height: 560px;
    width: 100%
  }
  
  #map_canvas img {
    max-width: none;
  }
  
  #map_canvas div {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div style=height:50px;></div>


  <ul  data-bind="foreach:uniquetags">
    <li data-bind="text:$data, click: $parent.setSelected"></li>
  </ul>


<div data-role="content">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```